# Match multiple strings in multiple NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, predicate

I need to select stories from a NSArray of XML by matching a string from an XML element against a list of strings in another NSArray

The XML contains stories, each story has three criteria, say 'Fruit', 'Veg', 'Spice', each containing a single phrase. A sample story might look like:

```
<story>
    <title>I love cooking</title>
    <fruit>Oranges</fruit>
    <veg>Cauliflower</veg>
    <spice>Mixed spice</spice>
    <blurb>losts of text and stuff....</blurb>
</story>
```

I have three dictionaries of key/value pairs in a NSMutableDictionary generated from a pList

```
<Fruit:dictionary>
    'Ripe bananas' : 1
    'Green bananas' : 0
<Veg:dictionary>
    'Green beans' : 1
    'Cauliflower' : 0
<Spice:dictionary>
    'Nutmeg' : 1
    'Mixed spice' : 0
```

I don't know what the keys will be, and I need to match the tag in the story against the keys.

i.e. story fruit tag:'Ripe bananas' MATCHES 'Ripe bananas' in list of fruit keys

I can build three arrays of the keys using

```
NSMutableDictionary *fruitTagsDict = [prefsDictionary objectForKey:@"Fruits"];
NSArray *fruitTags = [fruitTagsDict allKeys];
```

I loop through the story XML extracting a tag

```
for (id myArrayElement in storyArray) {
    NSString *fruitString = [NSString stringWithString:[myArrayElement fruit]];
    //BOOL isTheObjectThere = [issueTags containsObject:fruitString];

    NSString *vegString = [NSString stringWithString:[myArrayElement veg]];

    NSString *spiceString = [NSString stringWithString:[myArrayElement spice]];

    //if ([[fruitTags objectAtIndex:row] isEqualToString:fruitString]) {
    //NSLog(@"Yo %@", fruitString);
            // ADD TO A NEW ARRAY OF MATCHING STORIES
    //}
        // Fails because row is undeclared
}
```

Then I start to glaze out.

The isTheObjectThere line produces nil then crashes at end of loop

I've looked at:
[Filter entire NSDictionaries out of NSArray based on multiple keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457495/filter-entire-nsdictionaries-out-of-nsarray-based-on-multiple-keys)
[Making the Code check to see if the Text in a Text box matches any of the Strings in an NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361766/making-the-code-check-to-see-if-the-text-in-a-text-box-matches-any-of-the-strings)

It seems predicate is the answer but frankly I getting confused.

What I need to do in metacode

```
repeat with stories
    if storyFruitTag is in fruitTagArray 
    OR storyVegTag is in vegTagArray 
    OR storySpiceTag is in spiceTagArray
        Add to new array of matching stories
```

Hopefully I've explained enough to get some pointers, I looked into NSMutableSet and Intersect ([Xcode: Compare two NSMutableArrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437173/xcode-compare-two-nsmutablearrays)) but the power of too much information got to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way to determine whether there are matches using key paths:

```
 if ([prefsDict valueForKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Fruit.%@", storyFruitTag]] ||
     [prefsDict valueForKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Veg.%@", storyVegTag]] ||
     [prefsDict valueForKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Spice.%@", storySpiceTag]]) {
       // one of the story's tags matches a key in one of the corresponding dictionaries
   }
```